# Recover deleted user data — user deleted via System Prefs with “Delete home folder”

Tags: catalina, user-account, macos

Earlier today, I deleted a user (through the Users and Groups pane in System Preferences), and of the options “Keep home folder”/“Move home folder to deleted users”/“Delete home folder”, I chose “Delete home folder”.

Unfortunately, I realised afterwards that I hadn’t copied all the data I wanted from the account — I’d copied the “Documents” folder, but had forgotten I had some images in “Pictures” on that account that I didn’t have elsewhere.

**Is there a good way to recover the deleted files, in this scenario?** The only advice I can find from googling is to use third-party file recovery software; reviews of these vary widely, and most of them are fairly expensive, so I’d like to get informed advice before spending my money.

I’m on Catalina 10.15.3, if that’s relevant.  I’m very happy with using commandline tools if they can be helpful here.

Comment: Did you check the Trash?  Do you have a Time Machine backup?  You can try recovery software like [Disk Drill](https://www.cleverfiles.com/) for free *before* you spend money, but if  you’re using an SSD,  it’s likely gone.

Comment: I checked the trash, and there’s nothing there; and no, I don’t have a Time Machine backup of this.  (My personal laptop was away for repairs, so I temporarily created a personal account on what’s usually just my work laptop; so I was only using the account for a week and didn’t take a backup in this time.)  Thanks for the Disk Drill suggestion — I’ll try that.